# Using better includes for pages?

Tags: php, include

As of right now, the way I use includes is to bring the header, footer, and some content for other pages.

This leads to more includes then I really want, because I need to add more content for the includes.

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<body>

<?php include('body-top.php');
   custom html
</?php include('footer.php');
</body>
```

It would be nice if I could add variables to the includes and on the pages I want the includes to show.

I am not good at PHP at all, so is there a better way to use Includes?

Comment: What are these variables and why do you need them? Can you be more specific? In PHP you can always use a variable, just add them. What is your particular problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily done:

**index.php**

```
$title = 'Hello World!';
include 'content.php';
```

**content.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

The problem with this approach is, you'll soon run into problems keeping track what went where, so using functions as suggested in other answers might be a good idea. However, for small projects it's IMHO good enough.

Comment: quite contrary, using functions will make things obscure while within the same template everything would be clear and consistent

Comment: How would the variables look for including multiple external js/css?

Answer (score 1):

sounds like a job for [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)

It looks like this

```
<?php
require 'Smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php';

$smarty = new Smarty;

$smarty->assign('title','Hello World');
$smarty->assign('hello','Hello World, this is my first Smarty!');
$smarty->display('test.tpl');
?>
```

test.tpl

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{$title}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {$hello}
  </body>
</html>
```

Or even better way, use some of the PHP MVC frameworks, which will give you even more stuff (not just template system)

Comment: Are you seriously suggesting that someone just making his first steps should use an MVC framework?

Comment: I didn't see the line about "first steps", on the other hand, it can be suggestion to the future, he doesn't have to learn it now, and smarty is not difficult, not even for beginner I guess

Answer (score 1):

Your includes are already very few, no need to optimize them.

Also don't pay attention to people suggesting Smarty or MVC's because that will increase dramatically the number of includes (in exchange for other benefits, of course)-

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your included files into functions.  PHP has a neat trick where anything between curly-brackets (i.e. `{` and `}`) is only executed when that part of the code is reached.  This includes the HTML code outside of your PHP tags.

This could be our 'header.php' file, where we wrap our current code in a function.

```
<?php function doHeader($title) {  ?>
<html>
<head> 
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
</head>
<?php  }  ?>
```

Then we make a tester for it.  Whatever our tester/caller chooses to pass as `$title` shows up in our output.

```
<?php 
// All included here
include_once('header.php');
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<?php doHeader('My page title'); ?>
<body></body>
</html>
```

This produces the output,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<title>My page title</title>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```